# Rails tutorial Testing failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am following a Rails tutorial..
Here is my testing file

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get home" do
    get static_pages_home_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Home | #{@base_title}"
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get static_pages_help_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Help | #{@base_title}"
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get static_pages_about_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "About | #{@base_title}"
  end
end
```

This is the error message i get:

```
Failure:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home 
[c:/Sites/workspace/sample_app/te
st/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:12]:
<Home | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App> expected but was
<Home>..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

Do take a not that the error sometimes shows About/Help in place of Home.

BTW when i comment out lines 5 to 7 and replace #{@base_title} in each of the tests the rails test result is success then.

Really conflicted with what is going on here.

Comment: How do you generate the title in your HTML document?

Comment: <% provide(:title, "The Title") %> at the top of the html.erb file..
<%= yield(:title) %> inside the title tag.

Comment: Are you still at chapter 3.4.1 in the tutorial? That step should fail in that chapter. Or did you follow the steps in 3.4.2?

Comment: It was a typo error. I am at 3.4.4 (Setting the root route) now.

Comment: You might want to consider closing your question if it was a typo, the problem doesn't exist anymore and the question and the answers will not help other readers in the future.